# A confusion regarding Closed graph theorem

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I consider the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ and add the indiscrete topology on $X$. Now I take $Y=[1,3]$ in $R$, with usual topology.We define a mapping $f:X$$\longrightarrow$ $Y$ defined by $f(x_i)=x_i ,$ for $i=1,2,3$ as we see $Y$ is $T_2$; $\{1\}$ is closed in $Y$. It's inverse image is not closed in $X$. So  $f$ is not continuous . $Y$ is compact $T_2$ space and $f(X)=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\};$ closed in $Y$. $X$ is obviously closed  so the graph of $f$ i.e. $X\times f(X)$ is closed , which contradicting to the statement of Closed Graph Theorem; says that $f$ needs to be continuous. where am I assuming wrong?Thanks for reading!

The closed graph theorem says that let $f:X\longrightarrow$$Y$; $Y$ is compact $T_2$ then $f$ is continuous if and only if the GRAPH of $f,G_f=\{x*f(x)\}$ is closed in $X*Y$.

Comment: What is the closed graph theorem you're referring to?  The one from functional analysis?

Comment: I'm not sure which theorem you want, but it probably says "if $f$ is continuous" and not "this is only true when $f$ is continuous."

Comment: Now  I have added it;sorry to confuse you by the name

Comment: The theorem in question states that a function into a compact Hausdorff space is continuous if and only if it’s graph is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $f$ is the set $\Gamma(f) = \{(x,f(x)): x \in X\}\subseteq X \times Y$ for any function $f:X \to Y$.

In this case it's the set $\{(x_1,1), (x_2,2), (x_3, 3)\}$ which is not closed in $X \times Y$: e.g. the point $(x_1,3)$ is in the closure of the graph: let $O$ be any open set in $ X \times Y$ that contains $(x_1,3)$, then there is a box $O_1 \times O_2$ with

$$(x_1,3) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq O$$ where $x_1 \in O_1$ and $O_1 \subseteq X$ open, and $3 \in O_2$, $O_2 \subseteq Y$ open. As $X$ is indiscrete $O_1 = X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, the only non-empty open set. But then $$(x_3,3) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq O$$ as well and $(x_3,3)$ lies in the graph of $f$. As $O$ containing $(x_1,3)$ was arbitary, we have that $(x_1, 3) \in \overline{\Gamma(f)}\setminus \Gamma(f)$, so the graph of $f$ is not closed in $X \times Y$.

So this example is no counterexample against the valid theorem:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function such that $\Gamma(f) \subseteq X \times Y$ is closed. If $Y$ is compact, then $f$ is continuous.

as the closedness hypothesis is not satisfied.

Comment: +1 @Henno sir .  I don't understand why  you got suspended.?

Comment: @yasmine answering bad questions that should have been closed e.g.

Answer (score 2):

I think your point of confusion is that the graph of $f$ is not just $X \times f(X)$; rather, it is the set $$\left\{(x,y)\in X \times Y : f(x)=y\right\} \subset X\times f(X).$$
In general, this containment may be (and usually is) proper.

So in your example, the graph is the set $\{(x_1,x_1),(x_2,x_2),(x_3,x_3)\}$, which is not closed in $X\times Y$ since for instance the topology on $X\times Y$ can’t tell $(x_1,x_1)$ apart from $(x_2,x_1)$.

Comment: why? $X$ is closed due to definition of topology and $f(X)$ is closed due to finite subset in $T_2$ space; so the product  i.e. graph is closed

Comment: @SubhajitSaha $X\times Y$ is not a $T_2$ space, though. It’s not even $T_0$.

Comment: I will stress again that the graph of $f$ is *not* the same as the product of $X$ with $f(X)$.

Comment: ;thanks I get it ; its not $f(X)$;  but how did you say my graph that i said is not cl;osed;

Comment: okk! I get it ; not $T_0$ implies not proper subset is closed, thanks

Comment: The argument I gave above that your graph is not closed was an intuitive one: essentially, what a topology on a set does is it lets you distinguish points to varying degrees. If two points are completely indistinguishable, as they are for instance in the indiscrete topology, then any open or closed set containing one of them must contain the other.

Comment: Formally, since the products of open sets form a base for the topology on $X\times Y$, any open set $U$ containing $(x_2,x_1)$ must contain a base set containing $(x_2,x_1)$, which must have the form $X\times V$ (as $X$ is the only nonempty open set in $X$), where $V\subset Y$ is open and contains $x_1$. In particular, $U$ must contain the point $(x_1,x_1)$. On the other hand, the complement of the graph of $f$ contains $(x_2,x_1)$ but not $(x_1,x_1)$, so it cannot be open. Thus the graph of $f$ is not closed.

Comment: how did you say $x*Y$  is not $T_0$. It seems to me it's $T_1$; Let $(x_1,y_1)\in X*U$ and $(X_2,Y_2)\in Y*V$ ;  two neighbourhoods; Suich that U and V has intersection zero. Then $(x_1,y_1)$ is not in $X*V$ and similar for the another point; hence $T_1$

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your notation. The issue is that $X\times Y$ can't distinguish $(x_1,y_1)$ from $(x_2,y_1)$ since $X$ can't distinguish $x_1$ from $x_2$.

Comment: sorry again; that is ($x_2,y_2$)(My mistake was to press caps lock before typing) contained in $X*V$; $y_1,y_2$ are in $U,V$ respectively and disjoint also